# What is the command to copy the contents of "/media/sf_Shared_Folder/myfolder/" to "/var/www/myfolder"?

Tags: command-line, permissions

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a folder full of files in `/media/sf_Shared_Folder/myfolder/`. I want to copy the contents of this folder to `/var/www/myfolder`.

I prefer to use the GUI, however I keep getting permissions problems, so I'm trying to use the terminal but I am still learning the commands.

So what is the command I should use to copy the contents of `/media/sf_Shared_Folder/myfolder/` to `/var/www/myfolder`?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Please include the error messages of the "permissions problems".

Answer (score 2):

The `/var/www` directory is generally owned by the web server, which is why you are seeing permission issues when you are copying from the GUI. The simple answer to your question would be this:

```
sudo cp -R {source} {destination}
```

Breaking this down:

| Element | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `sudo` | "Super User DO", which means "do this (the command that follows) with root privileges" |
| `cp` | Copy |
| `-R` | Include subdirectories |
| `{source}` | Where to read from |
| `{destination}` | Where to write to |

This means that you would type the following command into your Terminal:

```
sudo cp -R /media/sf_Shared_Folder/myfolder/* /var/www/myfolder
```

If this is something you will do regularly, it may be worthwhile to look at adding your user account to the same group as the web server, or perhaps changing the source directory for the web server to the shared location

Answer (score 0):

The `/var` folder is a somewhat special folder in Linux (and other Unix operating systems). It is used by the operating system to write stuff it needs for log purposes, administration, etc...

I am not sure you want/should move your stuff in there. As a user you can read and run files there but not write, as the owner most probably is the root super-user and, unless you have access to that user, you will not be able to either change the permissions (`chmod`) or copy anything to there (`cp`/`mv`).

You most probably should not. You most probably should move that somewhere else.

Comment: Many thanks guys. I really appreciate your input and guidance. I will ingest the info so it helps my journey into Linux land. I'm looking for whatever it takes to save as much time as I can doing things, but at the moment as I struggle to learn, time is not my friend if you know what I mean. It's harder when the easiness of Windows habit creeps in. The analogy for me at the moment is working in Windows is like a racehorse on a racetrack, whilst Linux for me is like a horse on a  steeplechase track, so many jumps.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `/var/www/myfolder` is served by a web server or another web application that runs under the `www-data` account and that you want to publish some media files.

This will copy all the content of `/media/sf_Shared_Folder/myfolder`
to `/var/www/myfolder`:

```
( cd /media/sf_Shared_Folder/myfolder && tar cf - . ) |
( sudo su -s /bin/sh www-data -c 'cd /var/www/myfolder && tar xf -' )
```

---

But there might be a simpler solution for you. Take ownership of `/var/www/myfolder` and its current content. Note that it could make your web app unhappy. I don't know. So this is a bit dangerous. Use at your own risks.

```
sudo chown -hR ${USER}: /var/www/myfolder
```

Once this is done, you can drag and drop your files with the mouse.